# ¿Libreria PDF para PHP?

Tags: php, pdf

Quisiera saber cual es la librería mas fácil y cómoda de usar para descargar en formato PDF información de una aplicación web hecha en PHP. En un proyecto utilicé la librería FPDF, pero resultó un tanto tedioso maquetar los datos. ¿Cuál me recomiendan?

Comment: TCPDF está bastante bien y es bastante completa. Hay también bastantes ejemplos ya hechos. https://tcpdf.org/ Saludos.

Comment: Evita hacer preguntas subjetivas en las que cada respuesta es igualmente válida (p.e. “¿Cuál es tu ______ favorito?” o "¿Qué _____ me recomiendan?"). Lee [¿Qué tipo de preguntas debo evitar preguntar?](/help/dont-ask) y [¿Sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](/help/on-topic) para más información.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Te recomendaría por simplicidad **HTML2PDF** es bastante sencilla de usar y prácticamente lo que diseñes en ***HTML*** lo puedes imprimir automáticamente en ***PDF*** evitando el dolor de cabeza de tener que dibujar pixel a pixel las tablas y demás elementos que necesites en tu documento.

Puedes saber más en este enlace: [HTML2PDF](https://html2pdf.fr/es/home)

Otra alternativa (si no te molesta tener cierta integración con java) es utilizar **Ireport** que es una herramienta muy sencilla para generar reportes muy semejante a lo que es **Crystal Reports**. Navegando por internet encontrarás miles de formas de integrar **Ireport** con PHP sin complicaciones y te permitirá generar reportes utilizando prácticamente puro "drag and drop".

Más información sobre [Ireport](https://community.jaspersoft.com/project/ireport-designer) y sobre [integrar Ireport con PHP](https://github.com/PHPJasper/phpjasper)

Espero sea de ayuda. Un saludo!

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta @Huskie. He estado mirando esta librería y parece bastante sencilla. Pero me surge una duda, he visto ejemplos que convierte tu HTML en PDF, pero si tengo por ejemplo una serie de inputs rellenados con datos traídos de una BD, lo sacaría en el PDF?

Comment: Si. Cualquier cosa que ya tengas impresa en HTML la puedes pasar a PDF con esta librería. Lo mejor es que no tienes que armar "dos veces" una vista, es decir, normalmente con las demás librerias tienes que generar un documento nuevo con el contenido del reporte, en cambio con HTML2PDF sencillamente puedes reutilizar la vista HTML que le muestras al usuario en tu sitio como una "previsualización" y luego la imprimes tal cual estaba. Menos código, menos dolores de cabeza y mejor mantenimiento

Comment: Pues muchas gracias de nuevo. Saludos.

Comment: De nada. Me alegra que ha sido útil. Si llegas a tener alguna duda o algún problema con la librería pues crea otra pregunta y con gusto te ayudo a resolverlo ya que tengo bastante experiencia con esta librería. Un saludo

Comment: De acuerdo, lo haré si tengo alguna duda.

Comment: No todas las preguntas se pueden o se deben contestar. Ahórrate un poco de frustración y evita responder a preguntas que solicitan opiniones en vez de realidades. Lee [answer] para más información.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro Entendido Sr. Montoro. Mi intención era colaborarle y como el OP ya hablaba de una tecnología en particular no me pareció incorrecto dar respuesta a su inquietud. Me queda de aprendizaje. Le pregunto: Elimino mi respuesta?

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro Tengo una duda importante. He respondido a esta pregunta porque he visto la medalla de Reversión que da a entender que puedo responder a preguntas "mal formuladas o mal planteadas" sin ninguna penalización siempre y cuando mi respuesta sea buena. Eso no es contraproducente con lo que usted me ha sugerido? Y con el voto negativo que alguien ha dado a mi respuesta? Según la medalla que el mismo sitio otorga no veo por qué no debería responder a esta pregunta

Comment: No hace falta que la borres, porque ya está respondida y puede servir de ayuda al que pregunta. Sobre lo de la medalla de Reversión, efectivamente existe pero (según entiendo) no sería realmente para casos como éste. El problema no es que esta pregunta esté “mal formulada o mal planteada” es que es una pregunta que no está permitida en el sitio (ver [¿Qué preguntas debo evitar preguntar?](/help/dont-ask)) y de las que se dice en [answer] que no deberían responderse.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro Usted respondiendo a mi duda y yo publicándola en Meta xD! Pero entonces le pregunto: cuando se puntua negativamente una pregunta si esta cumple con las reglas del sitio? Si cumple con las reglas en cierta forma la pregunta nunca sería puntuada negativamente y entonces la medalla de reversión no tendría sentido xD! De todas formas ya me ha dejado claro que para preguntas de este estilo debo abstenerme de suministrar respuestas.

Comment: Que cumpla con las reglas del sitio no quiere decir que sea una buena pregunta. Hay preguntas que se ajustan a la temática del sitio pero no son realmente buenas (pueden faltarle código necesario para entender el problema, o estar escritas de una manera pobre, o no tener una descripción adecuada del problema...) y pueden recibir negativos por ello.